# Openlayers 5 serve local MBTiles

Tags: typescript, openlayers-5, mbtiles

I'm trying to serve tiles from a local .mbtiles in an Ionic 4 project.

Step by step I managed to download the mbtiles and to create successfully the source using [XYZ](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ.html)

```
new XYZ({
  tileLoadFunction: (tile: ImageTile, url) => {
    //stuff
  },
  tileUrlFunction: (c) => {
    return c[0] + '/' + c[1] + '/' + c[2];
  },
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

Basically, if I add the following line to `//stuff` it works (I took as an example a basic base64 string that represents a green square)

```
tile.getImage().setAttribute('src', 'base 64 string here');
```

But when I tried to retrieve the tile from the mbtiles using SQLite it stopped working. I tried various combinations of code but none worked as expected.

I could notice that it's because the `tileLoadFunction` doesn't wait for the asynchronous call to the SQLite database and render the image when is still empty. If for example, I use this code with the getTile function returning a Promise, it does not work.

```
getTile(tile.getTileCoord()).then((base64) => {
  tile.getImage().setAttribute('src', base64);
})
```

The fact is that it enters in the `then` and executes the local code and the base64 string that I get I know is correct. Apparently OpenLayers is rendering the tile before the `getTile` is resolved.

I also found out that the [tileloaderror](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Tile.TileSourceEvent.html#event:tileloaderror) event is dispatched for every tile, but I don't know how I could use it as an advantage.

Comment: Fetch the url then set the image src.  Similar to the example using xhr here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a specific url for every tile. I have only the locally saved mbtiles url that is unique for all the tiles and it does not provide the tile. To get it I need also to open the db and find the tile in the db. To use it I should have a server loaded locally which I don't. Or maybe I'm missing something? Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found to make it work.

Apparently the problem was not the call to a async function but the call to the `getTileCoord` function that I was doing to pass the correct parameter to the async function. I **do not know** why this happened but removing that call and changing it calculating the coordinates from the url parameter of the `tileLoadFunction` solved the problem.

The resulting code looks like this

```
new XYZ({
  tileLoadFunction: (tile: any, url) => {
    let coords: [number, number, number] = [0, 0, 0];
    let tmp: string[] = url.split('/');
    for (let i in tmp) {
      coords[i] = parseInt(tmp[i]);
    }
    coords[2] = -coords[2]; // the y coordinates is negative
    this.storageService.getTile(coords).then(function (tileBase64: string) {
      tile.getImage().src = tileBase64;
    });
  },
  tileUrlFunction: (c) => {
    return c[0] + '/' + c[1] + '/' + c[2];
  },
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```